# Solicitar un numero entero y con try hacer que sea un error y repetir si es un numero con decimal

Tags: python

Sinceramente no se que está mal con esa parte de pedir solamente un valor entero y que no sea decimal, si me pudieran ayudar sería genial. Todo lo de arriba si sirve bien solamente me falla el try.

## Funcion

```
def Temperatura(t):palabra = "NO VALIDO"
    if t < 0:
        palabra = "Temperatura Congelante"
    elif t >= 0 and t < 10:
        palabra = "Temperatura Muy Fria"
    elif t >= 10 and t < 20:
        palabra = "Temperatura Fria"
    elif t >= 20 and t < 30:
        palabra = "Temperatura Ambiente"
    elif t >= 30 and t < 40:
        palabra = "Temperatura Caliente"
    elif t >= 40:
        palabra = "Temperatura Muy Caliente"
    return palabra
```

## Programa

```
 while True:
    temp = int(input("Indique la nota en valor numerico (numero entero) :"))

    try:
        temp = int(temp)
        print( Temperatura(t) )
    except ValueError:
        print("No es un numero entero")
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio. Por favor, [no publiques imágenes con código fuente](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/21), copia y pega directamente el código en tu pregunta. NO olvides incluir de la misma manera mensajes exactos de error, si los hubiera. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varios problemas con tu código:

1. En la línea `def Temperatura(t):palabra = "NO VALIDO"` y suponiendo que lo que está después del `:` es la primera línea de la función, debiera estar en otra línea con la indentación del resto de la función.
2. Estás convirtiendo a entero dos veces, con lo que la segunda ves resulta innecesaria.
3. La primera conversión está fuera del `try`, por lo que si se introduce un valor que no es entero, no se va a manejar ese error.
4. Llamas a la función `Temperatura` pasando como parámetro una variable `t` que no está definida.

Las alternativas para los puntos 2 y 3 son:

- Quitas la conversión a `int()` del `input`, de manera que temp tenga la cadena ingresada por el usuario.
- Mueves la línea `temp = int(input...` dentro del `try` y eliminas la línea `temp = int(temp)` que, como ya he dicho, en este caso es superflua.

Corregir además los otros errores mencionados y todo debiera funcionar sin problemas.

Comment: Me funcionó muchas gracias :)